# Ubuntu 14.04 VBox Guest Additions problem installing

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, guest-additions

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual box but can't resize the screen so I want to install guest additions. I can't open a terminal window because I can't access the "start" button and when I type use alt + ctrl + T, the terminal does not open.  This means I can't resize screen until I install guest additions but I can't install guest additions without resizing the screen.

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+f1, this will start a command line interface (a big full screen terminal) then, from here you can install the `guest additions` then ctrl+alt+F7 will take you back to the desktop, when you are finished

Comment: Did you see this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also download the guest additions .iso file for your version of VirtualBox mount it inside and install it from there.

Go to [this link](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) find your version and download VBoxGuestAdditions_x.x.x.iso.

Then in the lower right corner of the VirtualBox window you should see a dvd  icon, click on that and navigate to the .iso file.

After that start up ubuntu and when it loads open a file browser and navigate to the disk and search for a .sh file corresponding to your os (linux, windows etc.) make sure it is an executable file (right click then propities and check `execute file as program` is checked) and run it.

After it is finished just power off, unmount the disk and it should be working on the next start up.

Comment: while this may be the correct answer it would be useful to include the information on downloading, mounting and installing the `guest additions` in your answer, to help other users.